# Someone gave me their account and routing number

Tags: money-transfer, scams

A friend of mine who is away wants to help me pay off my credit card debit. I don’t want to give my personal info out. He said that until I’m comfortable I can pay it using his account and routing number. Is that possible? How does it work ?

Comment: This is almost certainly a scam. You'll make some payment from the account, something will go  wrong, you'll need to pay them back, etc. Have ever met this friend in person? Why can't they just make the payment themselves?

Comment: I have not met in person. He’s is traveling a lot. And I’ve talked with him on phone and he seems genuine but honestly who knows

Comment: If this is legit, he can simply write you a check; all he needs is your name to do that. (Of course, you then need to decide if a check he writes will actually clear.)

Comment: @GlenPierce You should make that an answer.

Comment: Obviously not a duplicate, and therefore still unanswered.  This is how all deposits are made across borders. Heck for years, this was how ebay transactions worked, and broker settlements.  It is still common to "wire" money. This is not a stranger, but identity should be verified. Google SWIFT and educate yourselves.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly a scam. You'll make some payment from the account, something will go  wrong, you'll need to pay them back, then the payment from their account will bounce.

Since you've never met this person in person, their identity is probably false. They probably have been doing this to several people at once and have a lot of experience gaining confidence of others. Why can't they just make the payment themselves?

Comment: OP explicitly mentions the person is known to them, and between the lines may owe the OP for some of that debt. All banks with an internet portal should allow international transfers, if you do not know what you are doing ask the bank.

Comment: I think you've misread the posting as they say the person is "a friend" and later clarifies "I have not met in person."

Comment: Bugger, I missed that, and it should have been added to the question. That changes the whole context, even if a long game is played or employment is involved.